# Definición de clases anónimas en Java

Tags: java, poo

Mientras leía la documentación oficial de Java sobre [clases anónimas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), me topé con el siguiente código:

```
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

interface HelloWorld {
    public void greet();
    public void greetSomeone(String someone);
}
```

Hasta donde entiendo, ¿se crea una clase sencilla llamada `HelloWorldAnonymousClasses` y después se implementa una interface? según las interfaces se ponen después del título de la clase principal del archivo `.java`

Si me equivoco, me encantarían las críticas constructivas o al menos un ejemplo o comentario en la que me puedan ayudar a comprender el código.

Nota: leí los temas anteriores de la documentación y no veo nada similar a esto, si me equivoco me gustaría que me puedan proporcionar el link de donde esté.

Comment: Sería bueno que coloques el enlace donde obtuviste el código. Tal como luce, no hay un ejemplo de clase anónima.

Comment: Conociendo la documentación se entiende porque causa confusión en novatos.

Answer (score 4):

Se entiende la confusión, esta parte de la documentación de Oracle no esta muy bien estructurado, voy a dar un ejemplo corto, luego lo explico por pasos:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
            System.out.println(toString() i);
        }
    }
}
```

Este código asigna a la variable `r` un objeto de clase anónima implementando la interfaz `Runnable`, así se puede correr en una hebra.

La clase es anónima, porque tiene sus propias implementaciónes de interfaces o superclases, pero no expone un nombre propio.

En pocas palabras una clase anónima se crea cuando uno agrega un cuerpo a un objeto que uno esta instando. La llamada `toString()` accede directamente al método de la clase exterior en que se usa este código.

TLDR;

**1) La clase contenedora `HelloWorldAnonymousClases`**

Para empezar hay que entender que esta clase por uno es solamente una clase que encapsula ejemplos para el uso de clases anónimas, por segundo ni siquiera es funcional, y finalmente empieza con el ejemplo más esotérico que hay para clases anónimas. Lo que importa aquí es la existencia de una interfaz que sirve para instar clases anónimas.

**2) Tengo que declarar la interfaz para la clase anónima como clase anidada?**

No es necesario de declarar la interfaz en la misma clase donde quiero usar clases anónimas. En el ejemplo se hace simplemente para mantener todo el código dentro de una clase. Incluso se puede usar una clase o una clase abstracta como base para una clase anónima:

```
// un java.awt.Button
Button b = new Button("botón ruidoso"){

    // este método no existe en la clase superior
    void logAction(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }

    @Override
    void processActionEvent(ActionEvent e){
        logAction(e);
        super.processActionEvent(e);
    }
}
```

**3) Porque necesito una interfaz o superclase para crear una clase anónima?**

Una clase anónima se construye mientras se insta. Si no tuviera nada para instar, no podría hacer eso. Además, si una clase sería completamente anónima y ni siquiera implementaría una interfaz, sería imposible de saber que métodos o campos de la clase se pueden acceder, y la clase se quedaría inutilizable. ¿Pero porque puedo instar una interfaz, normalmente no se puede? En este caso puedo, pero tengo que cumplir con el contrato de la interfaz en el cuerpo de la clase anonima, implementando todo lo definido por la interfaz.

**4) Un simple ejemplo practico para una clase anónima**

```
// necesitamos una interfaz, en este caso un escuchador a un evento
public Interface EscuchadorEvento{
    public void nuevoEvento(Evento e);
}
```

La clase `Evento` es una representación simple de una evento que tiene un código y un mensaje:

```
public class Evento{
    public final int codigo;
    public final String mensaje;

    public Evento(int codigo, String mensaje){
        this.codigo=codigo;
        this.mensaje=mensaje;
}
```

Además tenemos la siguiente clase `Observador` a que llegan eventos de tipo `Evento`, en que caso se llama a `nuevoEvento(Evento e)` al escuchador registrado.

```
public class Observador{

    private EscuchadorEvento escuchador = null;

    public registrarEscuchador(EscuchadorEvento escuchador){
        this.escuchador=escuchador;
    }

    // el Observador tiene un método con que otros artefactos dejen Eventos
    public void fireEvent(Evento e){
        if (escuchador!=null) escuchador.nuevoEvento(e);
    }
}
```

**Ahora entra la clase anónima en el juego:** Una clase extendiendo `Observador` debe imprimir todos eventos entrando al `System.out` como log.

```
public class LoggerEventos extends Observador{

    public LoggerEventos(){
        // tadaaa: la clase anónima ;)
        registraEscuchador(new EscuchadorEvento(){
            @Override
            public void nuevoEvento(Evento e){
                muestraMensaje(e.mensaje);
            }
        });
    }

    private void muestraMensaje(String mensaje){
        System.out.println(mensaje);
    }
}
```

Como se ve, la clase anónima puede acceder los métodos de la clase exterior igual que cualquier otra clase interna. Otro uso típico para clases anónimas es el [callback](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42911/cual-es-el-prop%C3%B3sito-de-las-clases-an%C3%B3nimas-en-java/42920#42920).

**Que hace el ejemplo dado en la documentación de Oracle tan confuso?**

Comentemos el código:

```
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

    /* se empieza con la interfaz como interfaz interna
     / no muy erótico si ni siquiera esta visible fuera de la clase */      
    interface HelloWorld {
        public void greet();
        public void greetSomeone(String someone);
    }

    public void sayHello() {

        /* ¿una definición de una clase dentro de un método? ¿Se puede?
         / Si, se puede, pero es altamente exótico y tiene un montón
         / de limitaciónes. ¿Que han fumado?
         / aparte de eso se produce una clase que esta "anónimo" fuera del
         / método pero no es anónimo en sí. */
        class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorld {
            String name = "world";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("world");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Hello " + name);
            }
        }

        // Olé, olé instamos un objeto a lo clásico
        HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();

        // Y por fin la primera clase anónima
        HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            String name = "tout le monde";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("tout le monde");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Salut " + name);
            }
        };

        // Y otra más, ya que estamos de animo 
        HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            String name = "mundo";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("mundo");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Hola, " + name);
            }
        };

        // finalmente lo usemos.
        englishGreeting.greet();
        frenchGreeting.greetSomeone("Fred");
        spanishGreeting.greet();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        HelloWorldAnonymousClasses myApp =
            new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses();
        myApp.sayHello();
    }            
}
```

En sintesis: `EnglishGreeting` **no** es una clase anónima, podría tener hasta un constructor (que una clase anónima por razones obvias no puede tener) y sirve para puro confundir en el ejemplo. Los ejemplos de GUI más abajo en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) son mucho más entendible en el fondo.

Answer (score 0):

El fragmento de código que pones no declara ninguna clase anónima.

`HelloWorldAnonymousClasses` es una clase "normal".

Y `HelloWorld` es una nested interface.

Las clases anónimas se encuentran más adelante en ese ejemplo que enlazas :

```
HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
  String name = "tout le monde";
  public void greet() {
    greetSomeone("tout le monde");
  }
  public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
    name = someone;
    System.out.println("Salut " + name);
  }
};

HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
  String name = "mundo";
  public void greet() {
    greetSomeone("mundo");
  }
  public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
    name = someone;
    System.out.println("Hola, " + name);
  }
};
```

Las variables `frenchGreeting` y `spanishGreetings` reciben ambas la referencia a un objeto que es el resultado de instanciar dos clases anónimas.
Son anónimas porque en el código no se les da nombre a esas clases. Ambas clases anónimas son clases que implementan la interfaz HelloWorld.

También se puede hacer una clase anónima que sea subclase de otra clase en vez de un interfaz.

Answer (score 0):

Lo importante es diferenciar la **definición** de la **implementación**.

En tu código de ejemplo no se **implementa**, se **define** la interface `HelloWorld` anidada a la clase `HelloWorldAnonymousClasses`, dicho de otro modo, la interface esta definida dentro de una clase.

Cuando *"las interfaces se ponen después del título de la clase principal"*, estas declarando que vas a **implementar** -escribir código que cumpla con- la interface.

Una clase anónima que implemente dicha interface sería algo como:

```
HelloWorldAnonymousClasses.HelloWorld saludador = new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses.HelloWorld(){
    public void greet(){
       // Tu código que implementa el método greet
    }
    public void greetSomeone(String someone){
       // Tu código que implementa el método greetSomeone
       System.out.println("Saludos a "+someone);
    }
}
```

Para posteriormente invocar con:

```
saludador.greet();
saludador.greetSomeone("Stackoverflow");
```

Cabe anotar que cuando la implementación es dentro de la misma clase contenedora de la interface se puede omitir el prefijo `HelloWorldAnonymousClasses.`, por que la interface es conocida en ese mismo contexto.