# ¿Cuál es el propósito de las clases anónimas en Java?

Tags: java

No le veo algo de funcionalidad a una clase anónima.

*¿Alguien me podría explicar para qué me puede ayudar?*

Lamentablemente, no lo entiendo. Claro que leí su documentación en Oracle, pero no veo un uso en producción que sirva, yo la veo como si fuera un método.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clases anónimas en java se usan mucho por ejemplo en escuchadores, callbacks o eventos. La ventaja de una clase anónima es que puede acceder variables locales en su alcance.

Un ejemplo. Estamos usando un *Dao* que nos da el resultado de una solicitud a una base de datos en un *ResultCallback*.

```
public class MiDao extends AlgunDao{

    // buscar datos según nombre de columna para devolverlo en un callback
    public void getDatos(List<String> columnas, ResultCallback callback){
         // despues de ejecutar la solicitud, el DAO llama al callback
         // con un mapa de columnas y resultados
    } 

public interface ResultCallback {

    public void setResult(Map<String,Object> result);
}
```

Queremos en un controlador acceder a este BD y poner los resultados en las vistas que corresponden.

```
public class Controlador {

    private MiDao dao = new MiDao();

    // un método que agrega datos a vistas identificadas por un nombre que 
    // corresponde al nombre de la columna en la BD
    private void agregarDato(String vista, Object data){
        // logica que agrega los datos a las vistas
    }

    // un método para solicitar datos a un dao
    public void llenarVistas(List<String> vistas){

        // llamamos el dao con una clase anónima que implementa el interfaz
        // ResultCallback
        dao.getDatos(vistas, new ResultCallback(){

            @Override
            public void setResult(Map<String,Object> result){

                 // aquí podemos acceder métodos de la clase
                 Iterator<Entry<String,Object>> it =
                            result.entrySet().iterator();

                 while (it.hasNext()){
                     Entry<String,Object> e = it.next();
                     // llamamos un método privado del Controlador
                     agregarDato(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                 }
             }
         }); // final de la clase anónima
    }
}
```

Además podríamos usar cualquier variable local en el alcance de la clase anónima que esta declarado con el modificador *final*.

Comment: Hola Stefan, buena respuesta. Cabe mencionar que a partir de Java 8, las variables locales ya no necesitan el modificador `final` para poder ser usados en una clase anónima. Sigue siendo necesario que la variable no cambie (como si fuera final), pero el modificador ya no es un requisito.

Comment: Tienes una fuente oficial para lo de ya no se necesita el modificador final en Java8? Según lo que veo, Oracle todavía insiste que final sería necesario en su documentación. Y me parece cuestionable si es una buena idea de dejar el modificador como requisito pero aun necesitar que la variable no cambia.

Comment: Referencia: [Local Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) - *However, starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final __or effectively final__. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.* Aunque estrictamente hablando esa página no habla de clases anónimas, la [página en cuanto a las clases anónimas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) hace referencia a al mismo texto.

Comment: Y estas seguro que _Local Class_ y _Anonymous Class_ se tratan iguales en esto en Java 8? Esta implicado en [Anonymous Clases](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) , sin embargo más abajo se dice que el modificador **final** sería necesario. Parece que lo voy a tener que probar.

Comment: Sí, estoy seguro. Y por supuesto lo probé. Aunque no puedo estar 100% seguro del por qué hicieron este cambio, sospecho que fue motivado con la introducción de los lambdas. Tal vez quisieron parecerse un poco más a los otros lenguajes en la forma como estas expresiones hacen un *capture variable*. Y ya que lo cambiaron para los lambdas, aplicaron el cambio a las clases locales y anónimas también.

Comment: Y toma en cuenta que, aun en la página para las clases anónimas dice: *An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final __or effectively final.__*

Comment: Gracias para iluminarme, que suerte que la mayoría de mis proyectos todavia son compliance 1.6 o 1.7 :D Me siento tentado de conversar como Java empieza parecer un abuelo en patinetas, pero dejemos eso a otro lugar mejor :D

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, cuando Oracle recomienda que se siga poniendo `final` es porque así se aseguraría la compatibilidad del código con las versiones anteriores. Total, si es _efectivamente final_ mejor marcarlo y curarse en salud. ¿Qué opinas @sstan?

Comment: Yo por lo menos concuerdo, todo implícito deja dudas, y aun que parece más trabajo de declarar, declarar crea claridad, especialmente trabajando en equipo o en caso de trabajar en el código en revisiones más adelante.

Answer (score 15):

En pocas palabras, el uso de una clase anónima te permite crear un objeto que implementa una interfaz en particular y poder usarlo libremente sin la molestia de tener que definir explícitamente una clase.

Aunque nunca es estrictamente necesario emplear las clases anónimas (siempre es posible lograr un código equivalente usando clases normales), hay por lo menos 3 ventajas en su uso que se me ocurren, y que aplican bajo ciertas circunstancias:

1. Si hay *un solo lugar* en tu código donde se necesitaría una instancia de una clase en particular, el tener que tomar la pena de definir una clase entera para *un solo uso* se puede volver fastidioso. Una clase anónima es ideal para estas situaciones, y te evita contaminar tu proyecto con clases que no piensas reutilizar en otros lugares de todas maneras.
2. Sobre todo cuando la implementación es corta, el que la implementación de la clase se encuentre directamente en el lugar donde se usa, puede hacer que el código sea más legible y entendible.
3. Te permite acceder de forma conveniente a variables locales y miembros de clase sin la molestia de tener que definir un constructor para poder recibirlas y usarlas. (Aunque en cuanto a las miembros de clase, se puede lograr lo mismo con clases anidadas).

Para entender mejor estos 3 puntos, veamos un ejemplo donde típicamente se usan las clases anónimas: los escuchadores de eventos.

Por ejemplo, digamos que estás trabajando en un proyecto con una intefaz visual que incluye varios botones y necesitas definir lo que debe ocurrir en los eventos *Click* de cada botón. Esto se logra especificando un [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) para cada botón.

#### Usando una clase normal

Sin clases anónimas, te toca definir una clase completa que implementa la interfaz [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html):

```
public class Button1ActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField jText;

    public Button1ActionListener(JTextField jText) {
        this.jText = jText;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jText.setText("button 1 clicked");
    }
}
```

... que entonces puedes usar de esta manera en el formulario que tiene el botón:

```
    jButton1.addActionListener(new Button1ActionListener(jText));
```

Aunque a primera vista no se ve tan mal con un solo botón, imagina el fastidio de tener que definir una clase `ButtonXActionListener` para cada botón si tu formulario tiene varios.

Además, si estás examinando el código del formulario, no es inmediatamente obvio lo que sucede al hacerle click al botón. Es necesario abrir la clase `Button1ActionListener` para poder tener el cuadro completo de lo que va a suceder. Nuevamente, si tienes varios botones, para poder tener el cuadro completo de las acciones, necesitarías abrir y examinar varias clases distintas.

Y finalmente, nota que la acción en este caso es de modificar el texto de un campo en el formulario. Pero como la clase `Button1ActionListener` no tiene acceso al formulario, es necesario definir un constructor solo para poder acceder al campo en cuestión. Esto no es ideal.

#### Usando una clase anónima

Con una clase anónima, no necesitas definir una clase aparte del formulario. Puedes definir la acción para el botón directamente en el código del formulario de esta manera:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jText.setText("button 1 clicked");
    }
});
```

Nuevamente, imagina que tienes que definir este tipo de acción para varios botones en tu formulario. Inmediatamente podemos ver las ventajas en contraste al ejemplo anterior:

1. No hay necesidad de crear un sin número de clases apartes que no tienen ningún otro uso fuera del formulario.
2. Al examinar el código del formulario, enseguida puedo ver el cuadro completo de las acciones relacionadas a los botones. No necesito abrir un sin número de clases para entender lo que va a suceder.
3. Nota que el método `actionPerformed()` tiene acceso directo y conveniente a la variable `jText` y cualquier otra variable en el método o clase del formulario. Esto te ahorra código comparado a una clase normal (como mencioné antes, hasta cierto grado, las clases anidadas pueden ayudar con esto también, pero no me quiero salir de tema).

#### Usando una expresión lambda

Cabe mencionar que, a partir de Java 8, muchos de los usos típicos para clases anónimas se pueden mejorar usando mas bien [expresiones lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Básicamente, en cualquier lugar donde te toque trabajar con una interfaz que tenga un solo método (como es el caso con los escuchadores de eventos como [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)), puedes usar una [expresión lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) mas bien que una clase anónima. De modo que, aunque las clases anónimas aún tienen sus usos, a partir de Java 8 hay menos situaciones donde se favorecería su uso.

Nota cuan compacto se ve el código equivalente usando una [expresión lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
jButton1.addActionListener(e -> jText.setText("button 1 clicked"));
```

Una vez que aprendes y te acostumbras a la sintaxis de las expresiones lambdas, se puede apreciar que tiene todas las ventajas de las clases anónimas pero con una sintaxis mucho más compacta.

Answer (score 0):

La ventaja de las clases anónimas son muchas, pero la raíz de todo esto es el uso de las llamadas "interfaces" las cuales son auxiliares en crear clases lo más abstractas posibles para que después puedan ser reutilizadas (re utilización de código). Una de esas ventajas es que al pasar una interface como parámetro en una clase anónima, tu tienes la posibilidad de personalizar la acción a ejecutar y de paso puedes utilizar objetos locales a tu alcance. Así no tienes que crear otra clase que tenga que llevarselos por medio de un metodo que los capture:

```
void (JLabel lbl){ //Si quiero utilizar por ejemplo un jLabel para actualizarlo por medio de un cronometro en tiempo real
...
}
```

Si no que al estar en local sobreescribiendo el metodo de la interface, solamente mandas a llamar a ese JLabel local y haces lo que bien te apetesca con Él.

Y aparte de todo puedes reutilizar el código con otra accion diferente que te apetesca. Y así aprovechamos lo orientado a objetos que nos ahorra un trabajo enorme y un desorden enorme en nuestro código. Evitemos así redundancia de código.

Hacemos aveces clases que casí casí hacen lo mismo pero sólo cambian en alguna acción o parametros. Y es mejor hacer una sola clase que soporte todo.

Es como un tamalero que no solo sabe hacer tamales de rajas, tambien te los hace de mole, de verde, de dulce, jarochos, etc. Y una clase así es mucho más potente. Por que soporta de todo.

No se si me di a entender. Saludos.

---

En realidad sí es un método común y corriente.

PERO...

Ese método que en realidad es una interface, se va a mandar como parametro para que otro método lo procese y haga uso de el contenido de ese código.

Obviamente al ser enviado a otro método, la función no va a ser solamente lo que tu estás poniendo en la clase anónima, sino que también va a ser utilizado con una función extra:

Como por ejemplo ejecutar ese método en otro hilo diferente.

Cosa que no puedes hacer con un simple metodo solo.
En este caso el Objeto Thread lo requiere como parametro de su metodo run()
Para que por medio de un algoritmo, esa acción personalizada, que puede ser un hola mundo o lo que sea, se ejecute en otro hilo diferente.

Answer (score 0):

En (pocas) ocasiones he usado clases anónimas para mockear. No en código definitivo pero sí en pruebas momentáneas que necesito hacer en algún proyecto que no tiene las librerías junit o similares.

```
MyClass mock = new MyClass() {
    public String method() {
        // aquí mockeo el comportamiento del método para la prueba que
        // estoy haciendo, por ejemplo si en MyClass accede a BD yo
        // aquí hago que devuelva un valor fijo sin consultarla
    }
};
someObject.setMyClass(mock);
```