# ¿Constructores en el método main en Java?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy viendo un pequeño código el cual tiene el propósito de crear un software para crear un cliente y un agregarle el sueldo, etc., pero he visto y me han comentando que es incorrecto agregar el método constructor en el método `main` sino en la clase donde construyo todo los métodos, propiedades, etc.

¿Qué opinan?

Mi código:

```
public class HolaMundo{    
    public static void main(String[]args) {   
    }
}
```

La otra clase es esta:

```
public class Metodos {
    public int id;
    public String nombre;
    public float pago;

    public Metodos() {
        this.int
        //ETC
    }
}
```

¿Es posible agregar el constructor en un método `main` o deberías agregar el método constructor en la otra clase?

Comment: Mas que buscar la forma correcta de ubicar un constructor. Es mejor enfocarse en los conceptos detrás de la programación orientada a objetos. Por que nace y que problemas resuelve.

Comment: He agregado respuesta, espero te sirva, saludos. definitivamente no se puede agregar un constructor dentro del método main.

Answer (score 6):

1) **Un constructor es una función como una forma especial de un método(1) inicial para construir un objeto según las especificaciones de una clase:**

- El constructor en Java tiene exactamente el mismo nombre de la clase, y no define ningún resultado.
- El constructor se llama con la palabra clave `new` para instar un nuevo objeto de tipo "clase".
- Se puede definir más que un constructor con diferentes argumentos.

2) **Métodos (y constructores) se definen en el cuerpo de la clase, pero nunca directamente adentro de otros métodos.**

3) **`main(String... args)` es un método, precisamente un método estático.**
Aparte de servir como punto de entrada arrancando un programa es como cualquier otro método estático. La diferencia es que el método `main` permite recibir argumentos desde afuera de la maquina virtual.

**Conclusión**

Resumiendo estos hechos, queda claro que un constructor **no** se puede definir directamente en un método (ni `main`, ni otro).

Para aclarar un poco más la estructura donde se puede definir un constructor y donde no, un poco más información sobre clases:

Una definición de una clase siempre sigue el mismo patrón, y se hace fuera de código ejecutable:

```
 // declaración de la clase
 public class MiClase{

      // cuerpo de la clase

      // declaración de campos y métodos

      // campo
      private int indice = 0;

      // el constructor es un caso especial de un método:
      public MiClase(int arg){
           indice = arg;
      }

      // método
      public int getIndice(){
           return indice;
      }
 }
```

Las únicas clases que se definen dentro de código ejecutable son clases anónimas (más información encuentras en [¿para que sirvan las clases anónimas en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42911/cual-es-el-prop%C3%B3sito-de-las-clases-an%C3%B3nimas-en-java/42920#42920)):

```
 public Listener getListener(){
      return new Listener(){

           @Override
           public void onEvento(Event e){
               // reacciona al evento
           }
       };
 }
```

En síntesis, la definición de una clase puedes hacer:

- En un archivo propio con el nombre de tu clase y extensión `.java`
- Dentro del **cuerpo** de otra clase, pero fuera de métodos (una clase interior)
- Dentro del código donde instas una objeto con `new` como clase anónima, normalmente basado en una interfaz

Te recomiendo [este articulo](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/jon/family/jos/oop_es/oop1.htm) para obtener una idea de que se trata la POO (programación orientado a objetos) en Java.

*(1) Explicación hacía de la comparación de los constructores con métodos: Aun que el constructor es un método en el sentido de un [modo de obrar o proceder](http://dle.rae.es/?w=m%C3%A9todo), formalmente no es un método según la definición del lenguaje Java. En algunos lenguajes de programación el constructor (tal cual como el destructor) se consideran casos especiales de funciones o métodos y tienen más o menos características en común con funciones o métodos regulares. Para evitar discusiones dogmáticas quiero aclarar: Es una forma simple y común de describir un constructor como un caso especial de un método, sin embargo formalmente y técnicamente no lo es por una cantidad de diferencias importantes.*

Comment: *queda claro que un constructor no se puede definir en un método (ni main, ni otro)* yo creo que esto es falso. Ejemplo: si defino una clase local no anónima dentro de un método. Java lo soporta y es una forma de crear un constructor de clase dentro de un método.

Comment: Es incorrecto afirmar que "Un constructor es una forma especial de un método". Los constructores no son métodos, ni especiales ni de ninguna otra clase.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no basta con escribir preciso, también hay que leer preciso. Dije antes que nunca se puede definir un constructor **directamente** en un método, y en tu caso no pasa eso, el constructor se define dentro del cuerpo de la clase que se crea dentro de un método.

Comment: No veo el **directamente** en ninguna parte de la publicación, por lo que mantengo en pie lo que digo. Técnicamente, sigue siendo posible. Es como en los contratos: hay que leer la letra chiquita y darle todas las interpretaciones posibles a menos que sea cerrado :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza "Métodos se definen en el cuerpo de la clase, pero nunca directamente adentro de otros métodos." Como estamos en el día de los cavilosos, lo voy a desambiguear.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos tienes que explicar eso urgentemente a los ineptos por ejemplo en la [Universidad Técnica de Nanyang](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html#zz-2.9) o a la gente en [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), que aparentemente son igual de ignorante como yo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos sin animo de echar mas leña al fuego segun estos link https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5656/constructor y este https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(inform%C3%A1tica) basicamente dicen de una manera u otra que si son metodos especiales, si no es asi me gustaria que me dijeras de una fuente fiable para mirar pues yo los definiria mas o menos asi, solo es por salir de dudas. P.D: agrego estos link porque en los que proporciona Stefan no lo vi, a simple vista. Saludos

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no te preocupes ya vi alguno de tus link antes no los habia visto. Saludos

Comment: Stefan, en esa página de Oracle dicen " Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type." Y es cierto, los constructores parecen métodos. [Parecen pero no son](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50206/301). En Oracle no dicen que los constructores **son** métodos. A la Universidad Técnica de Nanyang les he enviado un correo electrónico a ver si corrigen ese error en su excelente tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes mandar llamar el método constructor desde un método main, pero no puedes crearlo dentro de un método main ya que en todo caso lo estarías sobrecargando.

El constructor, lo declares o no, existe; si lo declaras, evidentemente tiene que ser un método de la clase, no un método de otro método.

Comment: Un constructor no tiene que ser un método de la clase; Los constructores no son métodos.

Comment: http://www.mundojava.net/definicion-de-constructores-de-una-clase.html?Pg=java_inicial_4_4_5.html
http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.mx/2012/07/normal-0-21-false-false-false_103.html
http://programandoenjava.over-blog.es/article-32829724.html
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(inform%C3%A1tica)
http://java-white-box.blogspot.mx/2013/12/javaplayer-constructores-en-java-que-es.html

Comment: En efecto, es un error muy extendido. Te puedo citar ejemplos que afirman lo contrario como [12 Rules of Overriding in Java You Should Know](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/12-rules-of-overriding-in-java-you-should-know) (busca en esa página "Because constructors are not methods"). Pero todos esos ejemplos, en un sentido u otro, importan poco. El documento que vale es la [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). Tienes una explicación en castellano [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50197/es-un-constructor-en-java-un-m%C3%A9todo)

Comment: Hahaha la explicación es divertida. No es un método porque Java así lo quiere. Es suficiente para mí, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 2):

Hola la gracia es que el método main solo sea el punto de entrada hacia tu aplicación y desde ahí llames a tus clases y metodos, tu clase Metodos se Debiese llamar Empleado ya que eso es lo que representa debe quedar algo asi :

```
   public class Empleado {
// los atributos de la clase deben ser privados y su contenido debe ser
// accedido por metodos publicos
// **Principio de Encapsulacion**
private int id;
private String nombre;
private float pago;

// constructor vacio, sin parametros
public Empleado() {
    id = 0;
    nombre = "";
    pago = 0f;// los valores float deben llevar la letra ( f ) al final
}

// constructor con parametros
public Empleado(int id, String nombre, float pago) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.pago = pago;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public float getPago() {
    return pago;
}

public void setPago(float pago) {
    this.pago = pago;
}

}
```

y luego tu metodo main : el cual puedes pegar en cualquier clase

```
    public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Empleado empleado1 = new Empleado();
    empleado1.setId(5);
    empleado1.setNombre("pepito");
    empleado1.setPago(150.000f);

    Empleado empleado2 = new Empleado(5, "pedro", 150.000f);

    //informacion empleado 1 
    System.out.println("empleado 1  ID: " + empleado1.getId() + " Nombre : " + empleado1.getNombre()+" Pago : " + empleado1.getPago());
    //informacion empleado 2 
    System.out.println("empleado 2  ID: " + empleado2.getId() + " Nombre : " + empleado2.getNombre()+" Pago : " + empleado2.getPago());


}
```