# ¿Es un constructor en Java un método?

Tags: java, constructor, método

¿Es un constructor en Java un método? ¿Es un método especial?

¿Por qué? ¿Qué hace que un constructor sea o no sea un método?

Hay ejemplos en que se dice que sí es un método, como [Constructor en Java](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/normal-0-21-false-false-false_103.html):

> Un constructor es un método especial de una clase que se llama
>   automáticamente siempre que se declara un objeto de esa clase.

Y ejemplos en que se dice lo contrario como en [12 Rules of Overriding in Java You Should Know](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/12-rules-of-overriding-in-java-you-should-know):

> Because constructors are not methods...
>   Traducido: Debido a que los
>   constructores no son métodos...

Pregunto si un constructor es un método.
No pregunto qué es un constructor o qué es un método. Ni tampoco cuales son sus diferencias o similitudes. Estas cuestiones pueden ser relevantes para dilucidar si un constructor es o no un método, pero no son el objeto primario de la pregunta.

Comment: Yo creo que esta o una de sus variantes para definir y explicar que es un constructor -> *Un constructor es una forma especial de un método* es simplemente eso una forma en que la gente entienda que es un constructor ya sea en clase o en un articulo, sin tener que entrar en profundidad que lo que aria seria liar mas que hacer ententer un concepto. Preg.-> que es un constructor -> Resp. -> Pues un contructor es un contructor, pero que es un constructor pues eso un contructor se encarga bla bla tecnicismos ect. Preg. -> que es un constructor -> Resp. -> *Un constructor es una forma...

Comment: ...especial de un método* bla bla idea general. Creo que el uso de esa definicion es para explicar de manera que se entienda sin profundizar mucho o eso creo. Porque un constructor es eso un ocnstructor, y un motodo es un metodo, si quisieran que fuera un metodo especial quizas lo hubieran llamado metodo especial de inicializacion, o algo asi, Yo para explicar algo usaria una variante de metodo especial, que esta mal pues puede que si, pero la pregunta seria el fin justifica los echos en este caso o en un caso de explicacion. Saludos

Comment: Puedes tener lo mejor de ambos mundos @AngelAngel . Se puede ser correcto y tener una explicación fácil de entender. "Un constructor es similar/parecido a un método especial que..." sería correcto. "Un constructor es un método especial que...." es incorrecto. En el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) usan esa técnica, dicen "Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type. " looks like = parece.

Comment: La verdad es que parece mas correcto usar el enfoque que usted propone para explicar ect haciendo uso del *looks like* lo tendre en cuenta para cuando explique algo sobre el constructor, muy *constructiva* su pregunta, (para mi por lo menos). Pero tambien es verdad que existe mucha controversia sobre esto en libros ect. pero creo que su enfoque es el correcto. Saludos

Comment: Por la ironía de la vida me llegó este pregunta por cierre, porque esta basado en opiniones. No lo es. Es una pregunta de los inventores de Java que tienen el derecho de  declararlo como método o no. En todo caso no es lo mismo, pero tampoco tiene tanta importancia, según yo.

Comment: Acaso están migrando las preguntas de la pagina hermana en ingles

Comment: @MalCam En el caso de esta pregunta no. La pregunta ha surgido por si misma sin ninguna relación con la página en inglés.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Parece pero no es

En Java un constructor parece un método, pero en realidad no lo es.

**¿Por qué? ¿Qué hace que un constructor no sea un método?**

Muy sencillo, ya que no quieres que te hablen de diferencias: JAVA así lo ha decidido, por eso en su documentación siempre habla de ***constructores*** o ***métodos***.

Además, por esbozar una definición (basada inevitablemente en las diferencias),  como su nombre lo indica, un constructor tiene la capacidad de construir una instancia de una clase. Un método no construye, no crea, sólo obedece a la orden que le ha sido dada.

> Constructors (§8.8) **are similar** to methods, but cannot be invoked directly by a method call; they are used to initialize new class instances. **Like methods**, they may be overloaded (§8.8.8).
>
> Los constructores **son similares** a los métodos (parecen pero no son), pero no pueden ser invocados directamente por una llamada de método, sino que son usados para inicializar nuevas instancias de clases. **Al igual que los métodos**, pueden ser sobreescritos.

La documentación de Java siempre hace la diferencia:

> 8.4.2. Method Signature
>
> Two methods **or** constructors, M and N, have the same signature if
>   they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4),
>   and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type
>   parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

También:

> 8.4.1. Formal Parameters
>
> The formal parameters of a **method or constructor**, if any, are
>   specified by a list of comma-separated parameter specifiers.   If a
>   **method or constructor** has no formal parameters, only an empty pair of parentheses appears in the declaration of **the method or
>   constructor**.

[Aquí](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/) tienes un artículo interesante (en inglés).

Por ejemplo dice entre otras cosas que en una misma clase puedes tener un constructor (éste siempre lleva el nombre de la clase) y un método con el mismo nombre... los dos funcionarán de forma distinta, haciendo cada uno la función para la que existe.

En resumen, **un constructor parece un método, pero es sencillamente un constructor, porque JAVA quiere que así sea. :)**

---

Algunas diferencias esclarecedoras:

- La diferencia importante entre constructores y métodos es que los constructores crean e inicializan objetos que aún no existen, mientras que los métodos realizan operaciones en objetos que ya existen.
- Los constructores no pueden ser llamados directamente. Se llaman implícitamente cuando la palabra clave `new` crea un objeto. Los métodos se pueden llamar directamente a un objeto que ya se ha creado con `new`.
- Las definiciones de constructores y métodos parecen similares en código. Pueden tomar parámetros, pueden tener modificadores (por ejemplo, públicos), y tienen cuerpos de método.
- Los constructores deben ser nombrados con el mismo nombre que el nombre de la clase. No pueden devolver nada, ni siquiera vacío (void) (el objeto mismo es el retorno implícito).
- Los métodos deben ser declarados para devolver algo, y cuando no devuelven nada tiene que ser indicado usando `void` .

Comment: Muy correcto, +1. Nótese que no es que "no quiera que me hablen de diferencias". Si hablar de ellas ayuda a responder si un constructor es un método bienvenidas sean. Pero el limitarse a detallar las diferencias no basta para responder a la pregunta ¿Es un constructor en Java un Método? Cosa que sí hace tu respuesta.

Comment: La respuesta más completa y precisa.

Comment: Sería buena idea **traducir al español** para que todos entendamos!.

Answer (score 2):

### NO

Un constructor en Java no es un método y tampoco es un método especial. Se parece a un método sin Resultado, pero no es un método.

La [Java Language Especification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) es el documento de referencia del lenguaje Java.

Podemos leer en [8.1.6. Class Body and Member Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)

> El cuerpo de una clase puede contener declaraciones de miembros de una
> clase, es decir, campos (fields) (§8.3), métodos (§8.4), clases (§8.5), e
> interfaces (§8.5).
> El cuerpo de una clase también puede contener inicializadores de instancia (§8.6), inicializadores estáticos (§8.7), y declaraciones de constructores (§8.8) para la clase.

Podemos leer en [8.8. Constructor Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8)

> Los constructores no son miembros.

Si un constructor fuese un método entonces un constructor sería un miembro. Y la JLS dice claramente que no, que un constructor no es un miembro, por tanto no puede ser un método.

Answer (score 2):

**SI** y **NO**

- En el sentido de la palabra [método](http://dle.rae.es/?w=m%C3%A9todo) en español el constructor lo es.
- Técnicamente y formalmente **no** lo es, por lo menos no en Java.

Es muy común de explicar (especialmente a novatos en POO) lo que es un constructor, comparandolo con los métodos. Lo encuentro perfectamente válido, es poco productivo de ponerse demasiado dogmático. **Pero** si lo explico así tengo que mencionar también que diferencias importantes hay:

- Un constructor en Java no tiene un nombre eligible. Es siempre el nombre de la clase que esta construyendo.
- Un constructor no es dejado en herencia por su clase. Una subclase tiene sus propios constructores, dentro de ellos hay que llamar los constructores de la superclase (si no pasa implícitamente por el constructor por defecto)
- Como no hay herencia de constructores, obviamente tampoco hay sobreescritura (@Override) de constructores, tampoco se pueden esconder (si llamo el constructor de una clase, siempre voy a instar esta clase, nunca una subclase).
- De los puntos anteriores queda obvio que no se puede declarar un constructor `static` o `final` (no tiene sentido).
- El constructor no declara un resultado. No es necesario, porque el constructor solamente puede ser explícitamente usado con la palabra clave `new` con que devuelve una nueva instancia de la clase en cuestión, o como `super(...)` llamando un constructor de la superclase dentro de un constructor.

Aparte de eso tiene muchos aspectos en común con un método

- Es un bloque de código identificado por un nombre y los tipos de sus argumentos.
- Puede existir más que uno, pero solamente con argumentos distintos.
- Tiene un alcance (scope) y se puede ejecutar código en el constructor tal cual como en métodos
- Se puede modificar la visibilidad con `private`, `protected` o `public`.

**Resumiendo:**
Mirar el constructor **como** un método (consciente que no lo **es**) no pone la sanidad mental de un ingeniero en peligro, mientras no se pierde de la consciencia que hay diferencias importantes como arriba declarado.

Dogmáticamente insistir que "no es un método" sin referirse a la importancia de las diferencias es tan útil y pedagógico que decir a un niño "el viejito pascuero es mentira, los regalos trajo el cartero".

Comment: Es posible ser útil y pedagógico a la vez que correcto y formal y, en mi humilde opinión, es mejor que ser solo útil y pedagógico. Tienes un error en  "porque el constructor solamente puede ser usado con la palabra clave new". También es usado un constructor en conversiones y concatenaciones causadas por el operador de concatenación +. [JLS 8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8): Constructors are invoked by class instance creation expressions (§15.9), by the conversions and concatenations caused by the string concatenation operator +  (§15.18.1) ...

Comment: Si te tomarías el tiempo de leer las respuestas en SOes con la misma atención que la especificación de lenguaje de Java te pusieras más constructivo. Un dogma no es una humilde opinión, y la invocación de una constructor por defecto en casos de conversiones por autoboxing no es un **uso**. Entender no solamente de la precisión de lo dicho, pero también de la voluntad de entenderlo. Pudiste entender la diferencia entre rae:método y java:método? Afortunadamente no tenemos que explicar java solo con gramática formal o con código.

Comment: No se a quien le estás discutiendo lo del autoboxing. A mi no, porque nunca he mencionado el autoboxing en esta pregunta o sus respuestas o comentarios. La diferencia entre rae:método y java:método ya la entendía antes de que la explicases, gracias. Esta pregunta es acerca de java:constructor/método, en el título queda bien claro.

Comment: Discutible, pero me di cuenta que "conversiones y concatenaciones causadas por el operador de concatenación +" se refiere únicamente a este operador y no a conversiones en general, lo que hace la especificación incompleta. Independiente de eso creo que no es tan difícil de entender que existe una diferencia entre como el programador usa el constructor y en que situación se invoca un constructor implícitamente (en concatenación y/o conversión y/o autoboxing).

Comment: ¿Qué es incompleta? ¿La JLS? Si nos cruzamos en el chat tenemos que hablarlo. En cualquier caso, ahora veo técnicamente correcta tu respuesta, +2.

Comment: Podemos conversarlo si quieres. En forma corta: revisando la fuente me di cuenta que la referencia a conversiones se limitó al contexto del "+", entonces falta mencionar la invocación implícita en conversiones fuera del contexto de la concatenación. No la vi donde se enumeran los ejemplos de invocaciones del constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Para no iniciar un debate sin sentido quiero basar mi respuesta en lo que describe la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

> **[Constructores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)** Una clase contiene constructores que son invocados
>   para crear objetos a partir de la clase proyecto. **Las declaraciones de
>   un constructor son similares a las de un método, a excepción de que
>   utilizan el nombre de la clase y no tienen ningún tipo de retorno.**

**Un constructor es similar a un método pero no es lo mismo** debido a las diferencias mencionadas.

---

Por ejemplo, la clase [Automovil](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autom%C3%B3vil) tiene un constructor:

```
public Automovil(int iniciaCadencia, int iniciaVelocidad, int iniciaMaquinaria) {
    maquinaria = iniciaMaquinaria;
    cadencia = iniciaCadencia;
    velocidad = iniciaVelocidad;
}
```

Para crear un nuevo objecto `Automovil` llamado `miAutomovil`, un constructor es llamado por el nuevo operador:

```
Automovil miAutomovil = new Automovil(30, 0, 8);
```

`new Automovil(30, 0, 8)` crea espacio en memoria para el objeto e inicializa sus campos.

Aunque `Automovil` cuenta con solo un constructor, podría tener otros, incluyendo un constructor sin argumentos:

```
public Automovil() {
    maquinaria = 1;
    cadencia = 10;
    velocidad = 0;
}
```

`Automovil miAutomovil = new Automovil();` Invoca al constructor sin argumentos para crear un nuevo objeto `Automovil` llamado `miAutomovil` .

Answer (score -1):

Los constructores en Java son un tipo especial de método el cual coincide con el nombre de la clase y no tiene tipo de retorno , cuando la palabra clave new es escrita Java reserva espacio en memoria para almacenar el objeto también se encarga de buscar el constructor , los constructores a menudo son utilizados para inicializar las variables de instancia de la Clase

PD : Son metodos ya que reciben parametros y tienen logica dentro de su cuerpo, pero son un tipo especial de metodo el cual solo es accedido cuando se utiliza la palabra clave new

Fuente : Oracle Java Certified Associate (JAVA OCA 8 ).

Comment: Esto contradice a la Java Language Specification.

Comment: En el libro de Certificacion de Java 8 indica que son un tipo especial de metodos los cuales no tienen tipo de retorno , ni siquiera void.

Comment: @JoseFelipeCharbelPavezGass favor de indicar las fuentes y una cita textual o enlace que nos lleve a la cita textual.

Comment: Pagina 40 OCA Exam-1Z0-808 :Constructors create Java objects. A constructor is a method matching the class name and
omitting the return type. When an object is instantiated, fi elds and blocks of code are
initialized fi rst. Then the constructor is run.

Comment: Probablemente debiéramos quejarnos con Oracle y decirles que es necesario que se eviten contradicciones entre la JLS y la certificación OCA, sería interesante saber si en la certificación Programmer se indica también lo mismo.