# Diferencia entre un constructor de una clase a definir un método que cree objetos de la clase

Tags: java, poo

Soy nuevo en esto de la POO (programación orientada a objetos) en *Java*, ¿Cuál es la diferencia del constructor de una clase a definir nosotros mismos un método que cree a los objetos de dicha clase, ya sea inicializando sus atributos o no? Ojo, hablo de crear nuestro propio método que cree el objeto, teniendo como retorno un objeto del tipo de la clase.

Comment: Si puedes incluir ejemplos concretos con código, esto aclarará la pregunta.

Comment: No sé si estas confundiendo el hecho de especificar o no el constructor. Todas las clases tienen que tener un constructor, si no especificas uno, uno vacío será generado.

Comment: Si, eso entiendo de que si no defino un constructor, el compilador usa uno por defecto.

Comment: Posible duplicado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50197/es-un-constructor-en-java-un-método

Answer (score 1):

En `Java` **siempre** usas un constructor para instar una clase, y si es el constructor por defecto (que básicamente no hace nada).

```
public class Foo{
    public static Foo getInstance(){
        return new Foo();    
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo trivial se ven ambos métodos, como se ve en el constructor "tipo fabrica" también se usa un constructor.

Crear un método de fabrica puede tener sentido si quiero controlar el contexto en que se crean los objetos, se usa por ejemplo (pero no exclusivamente) en "Singletons", clases que nunca tienen más que un objeto de su tipo instado a la vez:

```
public class Foo(){
    private static final Foo foo = new Foo();
    public static Foo getSingleton(){ return foo; }

    private Foo(){}
}
```

Un caso importante para usar métodos de fabrica puede ser cuando tengo injectar dos objetos con referencias bilaterales (`foo.bar` y `bar.foo`), en este caso el método fabrica me garantiza que el objeto no esta publicamente accesible antes que se llamaron todos los métodos que tengo que llamar al objeto hasta que queda listo para el uso, por ejemplo un método `init()` para inicializar.

**Ejemplo:**

Tenemos una `Application` y un `Context`. El siguiente código **no** va funcionar, porque no puedo instar un objeto antes de tener el otro instado.:

```
public class Application(){
    private Context context=null;
    private Application(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    public Context getContext(){ return context; }
}

public class Context{
    private Application app = null;
    private Context(Application app){
        this.app=app;
    }
    public Application getApplication(){ return app; }
}
```

Entonces hay que cambiar a usar un método de fabrica así:

```
public class Application(){
    private Context context=null;
    private Application(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    public Context getContext(){ return context; }
}

public class Context{
    private Application app = null;
    private Context(){}
    public static Context getNewContext(){
         Context context = new Context();
         context.app=new Application(context);
         return context;
    }
    public Application getApplication(){ return app; }
}
```

O vice versa. Así evito publicar objetos con faltas de referencias.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia es básicamente conceptual, hay algo en Ingeniería de Software / Arquitectura de Software que se conoce como "Patrones de Diseño" lo que platicas como "un método que cree a los objetos de dicha clase" se llama patrón "Factory"; ya que es efectivamente eso, un método que crea objetos de cierta clase, normalmente ese método es estático y se llama de esta forma:

```
// Ejemplos de Factory pattern con diferente notación
// Java
User newUser = User.getUser(name, last_name, email, password);

// JavaScript style
var newUser = User.Factory.create(name, last_name, email, password);
```

Mira, puedes leer más en nuestra querida wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

La otra forma de crear objetos como bien lo mencionas es con un **constructor**, que también es totalmente válida.

Como dato cultural extra: la persona que toma estas decisiones cuando se está construyendo un nuevo producto de software se le conoce como **"Arquitecto de Software"**.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta escrita en Java es:

Teniendo esto:

```
    public class Ejemplo {

    Ejemplo(){

    }

    public static Ejemplo generarEjemplo(){
        return new Ejemplo();
    }
}
```

Cual es la diferencia entre hacer:

> Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();

o hacer:

> Ejemplo ejemplo = Ejemplo.generarEjemplo();

**En este caso concreto no hay diferencia** el objecto ejemplo generado es igual.

*¿Porque hacer una metodo dentro de una clase que te devuelva una nueva instancia de un objeto de esa misma clase?*

En el caso de que quieras aplicar el **patron singleton** SI.

El patrón de diseño singleton se utiliza cuando en toda la aplicación quieres mantener una sola instancia de 1 objeto y no quieres de ninguna manera que haya otra. Por ejemplo: haces un videojuego de fútbol, y quieres que que solo haya 1 solo balón. Entonces harías una cosa parecida a la que dices:

```
public class Balon {

    private static Balon instance = null;

    private Balon(){

    }

    public static Balon getInstance(){
        if(instance != null){
            instance = new Balon();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

La idea es tener el **constructor privado** de maneara que solo se puedan crear objetos de esa clase desde la propia clase.

Entonces cada vez que quieras utilizar una instancia del objeto Balon la unica manera que tendras de acceder a esta sera a traves del metodo  `getInstance()`

---

Tambien  **tiene sentido si la función que genera el objeto hace algo más con ese objeto** aparte de instanciarlo. Por ejemplo podria rellenar sus atributos de alguna manera.

Hay patrones de diseño que hacen justamente esto como por ejemplo el **patrón factory** que tienen métodos que retornan objetos pero con los atributos modificados de alguna manera o habiendo hecho algú procedimiento con estos objetos antes de retornarlos.

Si quieres aprender bien todos los patrones de diseño para que sirven y como se usan te recomiendo un libro que se llama: ***Head first - Design patterns (2004)*** El cual explica de forma muy simple los patrones de diseño más importantes y el porque se usan.

Answer (score 0):

Lo diferencia más básica es:

Se genera un método que nos devuelva una instancia de una clase porque dicha clase no tiene ningún constructor público. La única manera de crear un objeto de la clase, es desde el propio **método estático**. Estático porque no se puede crear una instancia tal que: `MiClase mc = new MiClase();`

La clase te quedaría así:

```
public class MiClase {      
    private MiClase() {
        super();
    }

    public static MiClase dameObj(){
        return new MiClase();
    }       
}
```

Otra opción es lo que comenta nuestro compañero @cgardev, el patrón singleton. Pero si estás aprendiendo POO, lo de singleton y patrones de diseño no creo que lo hayas visto con detalle aún.

Para finalizar, usar el constructor con el `new` es porque tiene, al menos, un constructor público, por tanto puedes crear una instancia de esa clase; Ello implica que no hace falta tener un método que me devuelva una instancia de mi propia clase, no es muy lógico. En fin, tendrías una clase tal que:

```
public class MiOtraClase {
    public MiOtraClase() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Entonces, para poder crear instancias de una u otra clase, tenemos:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiClase mc = MiClase.dameObj();
        MiOtraClase moc = new MiOtraClase();
    }
}
```