# cómo imprimir el valor de un constructor vacío?

Tags: java, poo, constructor

Estoy aprendiendo acerca de java y como se hace un constructor además el para que sirve y necesito imprimir dicho constructor vacío para así comprobar que no arroja algún valor.

Comment: Tu pregunta, a mi parecer, no tiene sentido. El constructor arroja un valor, como lo vas a imprimir?. Luego tampoco es que sea vacío (void), eso aplica para funciones/métodos no para los constructores.

Comment: Bueno si eso lo se , es lo que no entiendo , ya que la maestra nos pidió que demostraramos que no arroja ningún valor, así como uno que si arroje y demostrarlo

Comment: Tienes la pregunta exacta de la maestra???

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Es un constructor en Java un método?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50197/es-un-constructor-en-java-un-m%c3%a9todo). Dado que estás aprendiendo sobre los constructores, la pregunta referida puede ayudar a entender mejor para qué sirven, qué hacen y cómo funcionan.