# ¿Cuál es la función de "new" en la definición de un método?

Tags: java, android

Tengo ya un par de años sin tocar Java, ahora que estoy aprendiendo sobre app android me tope con algo, y es que quiero saber por como se conoce tal tema para investigar.

A continuación, muestro el método para crear usuarios en Firebase:

```
public void registrarUsuario(View view){
    if(contrasena.getText().equals(contrasenaConfirmacion.getText())){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo.getText().toString(), contrasena.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Las contraseñas no coinciden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Mi duda es en:

```
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
```

Específicamente en `new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()` en sí, ¿cuál es la función de `new`? Veo también que hay otro método (`onComplete()`) dentro del método `OnCompleteListener()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso es una **clase anónima** declarada en el momento. Se le llama así porque realmente no tiene nombre, pero no es más que un tipo particular de **clase anidada**. En este caso concreto estás creando sobre la marcha una clase que implementa la interfaz `OnCompleteListener` con el método que se ve.

Desde Java 8, este tipo de interfaces (con un único método abstracto) se consideran *Interfaces Funcionales* y son candidatas a implementarse usando ***lambdas***, con lo que tu código se podría reescribir así:

```
.addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(user);
    } else {
        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateUI(null);
    }
});
```

Puedes encontrar más información sobre las **clases anónimas** y las **expresiones lambda** en esta [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42911/cual-es-el-prop%C3%B3sito-de-las-clases-an%C3%B3nimas-en-java)

Comment: Gracias Pablo te lo agradezco. Si tuve que configurar a Java 8.

Comment: buena respuesta. Cambié un poco el título para hacerlo más descriptivo, no sé si se podría mejorar... mi nivel de Java no llega a más

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me parece una edición muy acertada :)